# Fixing width of rich:dataTable

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces

Im developping a web application using `JSf 2` and `RichFaces 4`. I use `rich:dataTable` to display data but I want to fix the `width` regardless of content.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the css style to the  `rich:dataTable` using the `style` attribyte . For example ,

```
<rich:dataTable id="table"  style="width:750px" >
```